# Import multiprocessing fails in python 2.7

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I've got strange error from python console:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 300, in <module>
    atexit.register(_exit_function)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'register'
```

Repairing python via Uninstaller options doesn't help. Any ideas what's going on? 
This incident happened after unusual termination of script with using multiprocessing.
Python is 32-bit version, Windows 7 x64.

UPDATE: Full reinstallation helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try this?

```
>>> import atexit
>>> atexit.__file__  # should display a similar path for you
'C:\\python27\\lib\\atexit.pyc'
>>> dir(atexit)  # should display the same list, including "register"
['__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__',
 '__name__', '__package__', '_exithandlers', '_run_exitfuncs',
 'register', 'sys']
```

It looks like your `atexit` module got damaged.  Fixing that may just be a matter of deleting `atexit.pyc` (if it exists).

Comment: Thank for the comment,
I think it could be a solution, but I've already reinstalled all files.
That's rude, agree.

Comment: The _good_ news is that when something goes wrong, it's most likely to eventually go wrong again ;-)